# What is a precise definition of a twisted fibration of one fern over another?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory

I am curious if there is a notion of a "twisted fibration" of fractals.  Since there are many classes of fractals, I'll ask specifically about L-systems.

How can we precisely define the twisted fibration of one fern over another?

I understand that the trivial fibration of one fractal over another may be thought of as a direct sum, and indeed, the $\dim_{Haus}B \times F = \dim_{Haus}(B)+\dim_{Haus}(F)$.

Can we twist the fiber significantly enough to change the Hausdorff dimension from being a sum to something more?